# Java 1.8 scanner import

Tags: java

My code is:

```
package apple;

import java.util.Scanner;

class bucky {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(bucky.nextLine());
    }
}
```

While running, it says "convert local variable to field @ bucky".
And also resource leak: bucky is never closed.

Comment: Hint: read java coding style guides. Class names start Uppercase. And as Hadar says: try to use unique names. And: use names that say something about the intended use of the thing behind it. "bucky" says nothing; what would be wrong with a name like "scannerForUserInput"

Comment: A very much doubt that there is any message like that "while running". Please be clear about which errors you get and when.

Comment: And what is the relation with tag "neon" ? ("NEON is a vector-processing instruction set for ARM processors.") - I'm going to remove that tag.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Eclipse 4.6 Neon... Eclipse isn't needed either

Comment: Try using the below code,   Scanner scannerObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(scannerObj.nextLine());

Comment: Thanks guys...I'm all new to this  ..kindly bear with me..

Answer (score 1):

Your class name and the variable (Scanner) name are the same (bucky). Try to change one of them

Comment: Although it is not recommended a variable name being the same as the class name is not an error.

Answer (score 1):

> It says convert local variable to field @ bucky

That is only a suggestion by the IDE. Mostly meaningless for your simple code.

> resource leak. bucky is never closed.

While correct, that is a resource leak that `bucky.close()` is never called, you really don't need it here, and it is often error-prone to close the standard-input `Scanner`.

And yes, you should change your class name to something more descriptive and `CamelCased`

Answer (score 1):

Its a good practice to start the class names with capital letters. As @Hadar pointed out,the problem is that your class name is same as the variable name.And also never forget to close the Scanner import. You could also learn about try-with blocks to avoid resource leaks

Comment: Thats not a problem actually..But its best not to name them like that to avoid confusion